# Text align in dataTables AdminLTE3 template

Tags: javascript, text, datatables, alignment

I used template [AdminLTE3](https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html) in my project. I try align header in datatables I add:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {"className": "dt-head-center", "targets": "_all"}
  ]
```

to this:

```
  $(function () {
    $("#example1").DataTable();
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false,
    "columnDefs": [
        {"className": "dt-head-center", "targets": "_all"}
      ],
    });
  });
```

but this not working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a problem due to Bootstrap 4. You can try adding `text-center` class to `thead` in your table. The following is an example if you want to add `text-center` class using jquery:

```
$(function () {
  $("#example1").DataTable();
  $('#example2').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
  });
  $('#example2 thead').addClass('text-center');
});
```